# Mac Bash doesn't seem to have skip-completed-text variable

Tags: macos, bash

While Googling for another bash tip, I found this page on .inputrc http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-inputrc.html, which exactly fixed what I was trying to do (put a trailing / on symlinks to directories), but as I read further, I saw that there was a way to skip completed text as well.  "Awesome", I said to myself, "this bugs me about twice a week".  So, I put that into my .inputrc as well, but it doesn't work, or even seem to recognize what's going on.  After logging out, and logging back in, this is what I'm seeing:

```
$ tail .inputrc 
set mark-symlinked-directories on
set skip-completed-text on
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ bind -V | grep completed
$ bind -V | grep skip
$
```

That is, bash doesn't seem to recognize it's there at all... Is there something wrong with the version of bash supplied in Mountain Lion? Anything blindingly obvious I've forgotten to do?

Comment: Wouldn't this be an issue with the readline library and not BASH?

Comment: Entirely possible it's readline.  If there's any particular diagnostic data I can provide for that, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skip-completed-text` is new to bash version 4.

Answer (score 1):

The: `skip-completed-text` is only in bash4.

On my Mac:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.37(2)-release (i386-apple-darwin12.1.0)
```

If you want install some opensource utilities i recommending you using `macports` (www.macports.org). Installing `macports` will give you one command called `port` and with it you can install things dead simply, like:

```
$ port install bash
```

will install bash 4 for you.

Answer (score 0):

Bash v4 won't make it to OSX. Might I suggest zsh, which is not GPL3.